# Unity - Create plugin using SocketIoClientDotNet

Tags: c#, .net, dll, plugins, unity-game-engine

I'm having some problems trying to create a plugin for Unity.

I have a simple plugin working that returns a string.

Now I want to have a socket.io connection from the plugin and I found a plugin called SocketIoClientDotNet. I have compiled mine to a .dll file and have it in my "Plugins" folder in my Unity project.

When I run the dll function from a Unity script I get the following error:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type
>   'Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.IO' from assembly
>   'SocketIoClientDotNet, Version=0.9.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. myScript.Start () (at
>   Assets/Scripts/myScript.cs:10)

This is my plugin:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client;

public class SocketPlugin
{
    public void Run()
    {
        var socket = IO.Socket("http://localhost");
    }
}
```

And my script in Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class myScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public SocketPlugin plugin;

    void Start () {
        plugin = new SocketPlugin ();
        plugin.Run ();
    }
}
```

I've tried building the plugin with .NET 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5

Socket.IO plugin - https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/

Files in my Plugin folder:

- sista.dll (my own dll)
- SocketIoClientDotNet.dll
- WebSocket4Net.dll
- Newtonsoft.Json.dll
- EngineIoClientDotNet

I've tried with and without the dll files and I get the same error.
I have googled all day without any progress. So I really hope someone can give me some help on how I can fix this.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086178/what-could-be-causing-a-system-typeloadexception

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. But no, I never figure it out, sorry.