# RazorLight with .Net Core 2.0 WebApi System.TypeLoadException

Tags: c#, razorlight

I have followed the following link to use a Razor style syntax with my email templates;

[Microsoft Code Razorlight Tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-use-razor-engine-089934a6)

I have implemented a static helper class for getting my templates.

```
    public static string GetTraderApplicationDeletedTemplate(Trader trader)
    {
        string templatePath = $@"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\EmailTemplates";

        IRazorLightEngine engine = EngineFactory.CreatePhysical(templatePath);

        string result = engine.Parse("TraderDeletedEmail.cshtml", trader);

        return result;
    }
```

However, when debugging the `engine.Parse` method is throwing a `System.TypeLoadException` with no further detail?

Now the `templatePath` is valid (as is the file name .cshtml)?  Does anyone have any ideas on what could be causing this error?

Comment: TypeLoadException can depend on loads of things. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086178/what-could-be-causing-a-system-typeloadexception#answer-16086422) for debugging tips