# work with .xlsm c#

Tags: c#, excel, xlsm

I tried to use Spire.Xls library, but it does not support .xlsm and when i convert it to .xlsx hasn`t saved it, same with Microsoft.Office.Excel.Interop.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string xlsm = @"D:\foot_Regular B07BNJ56GV B07BNK8S3Q B07BMX2NN4 with3.xlsm";
        string xlsx = @"D:\foot_Regular B07BNJ56GV B07BNK8S3Q B07BMX2NN4 with3.xlsx";
        //ConverXlsmToXlsx(xlsm, xlsx);

        //string xlsx = @"D:\1.xlsx";

        /* Load Excel File */
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(xlsx, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);

        /* Load worksheets collection */
        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

        /* Select first worksheet */
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets[1];


        /* Deleting first 87 Rows */
        Excel.Range range = excelWorksheet.get_Range("1:87").EntireRow;
        range.Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);

        /* Save File */
        excelWorkbook.SaveAs(@"D:\out_file.xlsx");
        excelWorkbook.Close(false);
        excelApp.Application.Quit();

        /* Release COM objects otherwise Excel remain running */
        releaseObject(range);
        releaseObject(excelWorkbook);
        releaseObject(excelWorksheet);
        releaseObject(excelApp);

        MessageBox.Show("Finished");
    }
```

Conver function:

```
   public static void ConverXlsmToXlsx(string path, string outputPath)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.Write(byteArray, 0, (int)byteArray.Length);
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
            {
                // Change from template type to workbook type
                spreadsheetDoc.ChangeDocumentType(SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(outputPath, stream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

How i can easy work with .xlsm files via C#?
Help please with it, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

[EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) seems to be the library to use.

You don't need Interop or an actual installation of MS Excel.

They have a [sample](https://github.com/pruiz/EPPlus/blob/master/SampleApp/Sample15.cs) how to work with VBA macros, but it seems your problem was just reading and saving files without touching the macros, so you should be good with their basic samples:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{
    // make your modifications

    package.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use ClosedXML.

> ClosedXML makes it easier for developers to create Excel 2007+ (.xlsx, .xlsm, etc) files. It provides a nice object oriented way to manipulate the files (similar to VBA) without dealing with the hassles of XML Documents. It can be used by any .NET language like C# and VisualBasic.NET.

You can find [more details here.](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Basic-Table)

Comment: string path = @"D:\foot_Regular3.xlsm";
                var workbook = new XLWorkbook(path);
throws "System.TypeLoadException" in mscorlib.dll

Comment: It could be several things. You can check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16086422/7147323)

Answer (score 0):

Spire.XLS supports .xlsm files, here is the code to directly delete rows from a xlsm file with it:

```
Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
workbook.LoadFromFile("Input.xlsm");

Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

sheet.DeleteRow(1,87);

workbook.SaveToFile("Output.xlsm", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
```

I use the [Spire.XLS Pack(Hotfix) Version:8.6.6](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Download/download-excel-for-net-now.html)