# how to debug system typeloadexception old VS

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, sql-server-ce, windows-mobile

First of all, I already had a look at [What could be causing a System.TypeLoadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086178/what-could-be-causing-a-system-typeloadexception), and it did not solve my issue.

I am currently working with old, old, old, old code, writen in vb.net and csharp. This very old code was built with VS 2008, it is for a device that runs Windows Mobile, and the solution contains a few sdf files (databases).

I have already look at the top link and it is suggested to use fuslogvw.exe, but according to the documentation it is for VS 2019, so not for me.

The error is when I tried to get the computer name, any ideas of how to debug it? Everything that I have looked is for more modern VS

Comment: fuslogvw is for older versions of Visual Studio, not just 2019, as I've used it in the past to debug issues in a solution in VS 2013.  In fact, I think it's part of Windows (or .NET) rather than Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, in windows, modules we can see the libraries, dlls and pdbs that were pull through. The problem was that one pdb was being blocked from being updated.